# Are `.text` and `.data` really the same?

Tags: linux, assembly, memory-address

In the documentation for the Linux syscall `ptrace`, I saw the following text:

> --snip--
>
> Linux does not have separate text and data address space, so
>
> --snip--

To what extent is this really the case? Are `.text` and `.data` really stored as one? Does that mean that I can go about defining things like I would in `data` in `text`?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can define read only data in `.text`. What that sentence means is that the process has a single unified address space that contains both the code and the data, whatever sections they may be in.

Comment: That's not what they're saying.  They're in *separate* regions of one flat virtual address-space.  On a Harvard machine, address `0x1000` as a data address might access different bytes than address `0x1000` as a code address, because they're the same offset into different address *spaces*.  Like how the same offset in two different files are different.  But Linux's memory model doesn't work that way; all page addresses unique integers.

Comment: The key to that phrase is "address space".  You're reading it as if "Linux does not have separate text and data sections",  The terms address space and section are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what they're saying. They're in separate regions of one flat virtual address-**space**.

On a Harvard machine, address `0x1000` as a data address would access different bytes than address `0x1000` as a code address, because they're addresses in different address spaces.  Having multiple address-spaces is like street addresses, where 123 Church St. is a different house (memory cell) than 123 Turing St.

But Linux's memory model doesn't work that way; all page addresses unique integers because there's only one virtual memory address-space per process.

So you can draw a memory map where the `.text` and `.data` sections are different parts of the same space.  They get mapped with different permissions (read+exec vs. read+write), assuming you didn't use any special linker options, but an `unsigned char *` can read bytes from either of them.